# Call zuluCrypt for all the passwords in a text file

Tags: bash, passwords

I would like to write bash script to execute command:

```
zuluCrypt-cli -o -d /home/user/Desktop/recovery/test -t plain -p $PASSWORD -m EXT-TEST
```

My requirements:

- in PASSWORD file should be one line from `PASSWORD.txt` (each line one password)
- and when password is not correct `zuluCrypt` give me ERROR: `Volume could not be opened` then try again with next line from that PASSWORD.txt file etc.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
to be edited by user
```

But I get this error:

> ```
> error message
> ```

or an unexpected behavior...

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Try something and come back with an actual question.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{ resp=system("zuluCrypt-cli -o -d /home/user/Desktop/recovery/test -t plain -p "$0" -m EXT-TEST");if (resp!=0) { print "ERROR - "$0" Password is incorrect" } }' PASSWORD.txt
```

The above awk solution will read the passwords in from PASSWORD.txt as $0 and then use this to generate the zulucrypt command to execute. This is then executed with the awk system function and the exit code returned in the variable resp. This is then checked and an error message printed where required.

Comment: If all the passwords are on one line each, the script will work. If they aren't then you will need to give an indication of the exact format (how many password per line? How are they separated?)